# AFNetworking good examples

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, afnetworking

I am looking for very well written github projects with AFNetworking library and JSON. I would like to learn some  good practicies how to make a good class with multiple get/post requests from API. It can use twitter/facebook/forecast or any other API.

Comment: You are looking for good examples or short/quick examples. Because as jshier says AFNetworking is well written itself.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář I am looking for good examples. Yes you are right about jshier answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking itself includes example iOS and OS X applications that use the App.net API.